# A trigonometry question from STEP examination

Tags: trigonometry

Show that if at least one of the four angles A ± B ± C is a multiple of π, then
$$\sin^4A + \sin^4 B + \sin^4 C − 2 \sin^2 B \sin^2 C − 2 \sin^2 C \sin^2 A
− 2 \sin^2 A \sin^2 B + 4 \sin^2 A \sin^2 B \sin^2 C = 0$$

**I want to start with proving $\sin(A+B+C)$ or $(\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C))^2$, however, I failed in both cases.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the following information may help you towards a solution.

since all the sine terms are squared we may as well assume that A,B and C are the angles of a triangle. let the sides be $a,b,c$ in the usual configuration. then if $\Delta$ represents the area of the triangle we have the two relations:
$$
\Delta = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
$$
and
$$
R = \frac{abc}{4\Delta}
$$
where $s = \frac{a+b+c}2$ is the semi-perimeter and $R$ is the circumradius.

if you eliminate $\Delta$ and substitute for $s$ you have a polynomial relation in $a,b,c$ which will give you the required result after applying the sine rule:
$$
\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = 2R
$$

Comment: *"we may as well assume that $A$,$B$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle"* But then you assume $A+B+C=\pi$. It's stronger than the assumption in the question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut .  There IS another case. If $A\pm B\pm C=\pi$ then there are non-negative $A',B',C'$ with $A'+B'+C'=\pi$ and $ |\sin A|=|\sin A'|,\;|\sin B|=|\sin B'|,\;|\sin C|=\sin C'|.$  And if none of $A',B',C'$ is zero then we do have a triangle. But there is a "degenerate" case, which is an easy case. E.g. if $C'=0 $ then $\sin C'=0$ and the equation simplifies to $0=\sin^4 A'+\sin^4 B'-2\sin^2 A' \sin^2 B'=(\sin^2 A'-\sin^2 B')^2,$ and since $\pi=A'+B',$ we also have $\sin A'=\sin B'.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Ah, yes, we don't change the sines in absolute value, so we can indeed assume $A+B+C=\pi$. Nice!

Comment: @David Holden  the proof is splendid,but what make u think of constructing the triangle in terms of the semi-perimeter and R?

Comment: @Kevin well i stared at it for a while. brute force looked unappealing, so i felt stumped. then i thought of trying to get a simplification using the sine rule, but the slight 'inhomogeneity' seemed a problem (the term with three sine squared factors). after a bit more staring into space i vaguely remembered once getting the abc/4R formula for triangle area. this would dissolve the inhomogeneity, so the other terms must somehow resolve into the other well-known expression (Heron's formula). 1/2

Comment: then i thought i was probably wishful thinking... but after a coffee break, a quick bit of scribbling on the back of an envelope suggested i might be on the right track after all. fortunately in this case i was. such positive outcomes are rare, as my logic circuits are rather unreliable

Comment: @DavidHolden thank a lot,btw did u try to use substituting sin(a+b) for sin(c), i was trying to prove in this way initially but i got stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

First of all writing $\sin A=a$ etc.,

$$a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2-2b^2c^2-2c^2a^2=(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2-(2ab)^2$$

$$=(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(a-b-c)$$

Now if $A+B+C=\pi$

by [this](https://socratic.org/questions/if-a-b-c-pi-then-prove-that-sina-sinb-sinc-4cos-a-2-cos-b-2-cos-c-2) $\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=4\cos\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac C2$

and by [this](https://brainly.in/question/1593669) $\sin A+\sin B-\sin C=4\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2\cos\dfrac C2$

Use $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$

We shall same expressions in some order if $A\pm B\pm C=\pi$